# FlatList ScrollToIndex with onEndReached

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList of comments of **different height** and I need to implement scrolling to some specific element when opening the modal with this FlatList.

For some reason the method onEndReached is being called several times if I put ScrollToIndex in my ComponentDidMount. Is there any workarounds to scroll to the concrete element of the list?

scrollToOffset, initialScroll are not an options because I have different heights.

Tried to use this tip and 
[scrollToIndex inside promise](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13202#issuecomment-295134924)

If I click the button again it works fine but for the first opening the position is slightly different, like it doesn't have time to scroll or something.

```
  render() {
    const { comments } = this.props;
    return (
        <FlatList
          data={comments}
          refreshing={false}
          ref = {(ref) => {this.flatListRef = ref}}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          onRefresh={this.refresh}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          onEndReached={this.fetchMore}
          //initialScrollIndex={8} // works only for android
          onScrollToIndexFailed={()=>{}}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
          // removeClippedSubviews // dont uncomment!!! cause init white list on IOS
          ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmpty}
        />
    );
  }
   componentDidMount (){
      let wait = new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(resolve, 400)
      });
      wait.then( () => {
          if(this.props.elementToScrollIndex && this.props.comments) {
            this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({
              index: this.props.elementToScrollIndex,
              viewPosition: 0
            });
          }
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatlist can be considered as a loop of items, rendered one by one. So, the other possible working option is to scroll to each item, after it has been rendered.

```
renderItem({ item, index }: {item: CommentType, index: number}) { 
  if(this.flatListRef &&
     this.props.elementToScrollIndex &&
     index <= this.props.elementToScrollIndex) {
       setTimeout(()=>{
         this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({ index: index });
       }
  }
  return (<Comment item={item} index={index} />);
}
```